# ActiveMQ MessageConsumer behavior on failover

Tags: java, activemq-classic, failover

I have an application that registers a static list of MessageConsumer objects at startup and does things in the background (via the MessageListener objects) when messages come in. I want to make sure my code handles failover correctly. If failover happens, will the MessageConsumer objects automatically carry over to the failed over connection or do I need to recreate the consumers? Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
public class ActiveMQHandler {
    private final List<MessageConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Connection connection; 
    private final Session session;       

    public class ActiveMQHandler() {
         String url = "failover(ssl://...,ssl://...)";
         ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(url);
         connection = factory.createConnection();
         connection.start();
         session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         ...
         MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(...);
         consumer.setMessageListener(...); // will these still trigger after failover or do I need to recreate the consumer?
         consumers.add(consumer);
         ...
    }

    public void shutdown() {
         // close everything
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of the failover transport is to make the process as transparent as can be so yes, if you've created a consumer then the failover transport will recreate that resource with the broker on reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You need a strategy over time when failures recover.

In the case of a failure that occurred for a short time, the existing(or new) consumer will try to connect to another broker according to the transport option.

**That is a reason why no action is required but need to add more configuration to URI. based on your ActiveMQ version**
Refer to the following document for proper failover options.   : [Failover Transport Reference](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html)

However, if the failure persists for a long time, it can be different situation.
It's up to transport option(maxReconnectAttempts) or what your application do.

This is out of your point but this is important, Factory and connection should be separated into global variables (a.k.a singleton). Factory and connection are expensive for initial creation.
[Lessons learned: ActiveMQ, Apache Camel and connection pooling](https://blog.christianposta.com/lesson-learned/lessons-learned-activemq-apache-camel-and-connection-pooling/)

Note that you make sure all brokers have failover transport configuration and don't forget to add log while retry connection. Because it look like not work.